# Global Template Parameters in Django

Tags: django, templates, global-variables, global

Is there any solution for setting some variables accessible in all templates without setting parameters in each views?

For example, if I login the system, the var = 1, and all templates can use var value.

Answer (score 5):

(pre note: it is a good practice to always use these `RequestContext`s even if you don't need global data YET, because you never know if, upon a change, you will need global data later).

Use a [Template Context Processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) and use `RequestContext`s for each of your templates when you return from your views. When you send a RequestContext(request) as context for your templates inside your views, they will have all the data provided for each registered Context Processor.

e.g. consider this view:

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'foo': 'bar',
    }, [ip_address_processor])
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c)) #or use render_to_resonse('yourtemplate', c)
```

if you had a context processor like:

```
def foos(request):
    return {'var': 1} #this is the data this CP provides to each of your requests.
    #yes, data must be a dict-like object.
```

you will have `var` as a variable in every request, in every template using RequestContext(request). Your prev. view would have both `foo` and `var` variables available (passing a dict-like argument as the second parameter for RequestContext is like passing that value directly to the render method or the render_to_response shortcut function; using the RequestContext(request, data) let's you enjoy all the data provided by your context processors).

If you use Django's Class-based views or the `render()` shortcut (and not the `render_to_response` shortcut), a `RequestContext` instance will automatically be used as the context.

REMEMBER that you must APPEND to the default values, instead of overriding the tuple. e.g.:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"path.to.foos")
```

in your settings.py file (all but the last, are the default context processors used in django 1.5). **Otherwise you'd be losing most of the required CPs by the django core or many packages** (yes, IMHO an ugly caveat, but if you override you must specify the default ones as well)

Comment: Thank you Luis, that is exactly what I want and it works well. Thank you very mcuh!